# Suggested Integration Technique for $\text{sinc}^2(x)/\sqrt{x^2+c^2}$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, approximation-theory

I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\text{sinc}^2(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 +c^2}}dx$$
where $c \in\ \mathbb{R}$ and $\text{sinc}(x):=\sin(x)/x$.

I've tried the residue theorem, but this failed because of branch points at $x=\pm ic$.

Am I missing an obvious approach, or is it likely that an analytic solution to this integral does not exist? Alternatively, are there any approaches for a clever analytic *approximation* to the integral? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: With some change of variable you should be able to remove the branch points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is an explicit analytical solution to this problem. You can write the integral as
$$I=\mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \!dx\,\frac{1-e^{2 i x}}{2 x^2 \sqrt{c^2+x^2}} $$
You can deform the integration contour such that you only pick up the branch point at $x= ic$ (with the branch cut of the root along the imaginary axis). In this way, you can show that (I assume $c>0$)
$$I = \frac{\pi}{c} - 2\int_c^\infty \!d\xi\, \frac{1-e^{-2\xi}}{2 \xi^2 \sqrt{\xi^2 -c^2}}= \frac{\pi}{c} - \frac{1}{ c^2} + \int_c^\infty \!d\xi\, \frac{e^{-2\xi}}{\xi^2 \sqrt{\xi^2 -c^2}}$$ where $x=i \xi$.

We can get a good approximation for the remaining integral in the regime $c\gtrsim 1$ by expanding everything except for the exponential around $\xi =c$. We obtain the (asymptotic) expansion
$$\int_c^\infty \!d\xi\, \frac{e^{-2\xi}}{2 \xi^2 \sqrt{\xi^2 -c^2}} =
\int_c^\infty \!d\xi\, e^{-2\xi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} c^{5/2} (\xi-c)^{1/2}} - \frac{9 (\xi-c)^{1/2}}{4 \sqrt{2}c^{7/2}} + O(\xi-c)^{3/2} \right) = \sqrt{\pi}e^{-2c} \left[\frac12c^{-5/2} -\frac{9}{32}c^{-7/2} +O(c^{-9/2}) \right]. $$

Thus, we have
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{c} -\frac{1}{c^2}$$
up to terms which decay as $e^{-2c}$. In particular,
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{c} -\frac{1}{c^2}+\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2c} \left[\frac12c^{-5/2} -\frac{9}{32}c^{-7/2} +O(c^{-9/2}) \right]$$

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer! I can follow your work to arrive at the $\pi/c$ term [from the 1st order pole on the contour at $x=0$], but I'm having trouble understanding the $2\int_{c}^{\infty}...d\xi$ term. From my approach, I use a keyhole contour around the branch point at $x=ic$ and find that the integral from $\int_{c}^{\infty}...d\xi$ cancels the integral from $\int_{\infty}^{c}...d\xi$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JTT: the keyhole contour is correct. Where you go wrong is that you should consider the correct branch of the square-root. The function should be analytically continued from the real line. You will observe that on the two sides of the keyhole (along the imaginary axis), the square-root will not coincide but differ by a minus sign.

Comment: Thanks! I follow your logic but here's my trouble.
I'm avoiding crossing the branch cut at $z=ic$ by using $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ that varies from $\theta=-3\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. But, I don't pick up a negative sign because $$\sqrt{z^2+c^2}=z\sqrt{1+\frac{c^2}{z^2}}$$
What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: @JTT: you should tell me what the branch cut of the square-root is (otherwise, I do not know what you are doing). Let us understand that $\sqrt{z^2+c^2} = \sqrt{(z-ic) (z+ic)}$. The factor $z+ic$ does not bother, as we stay away from that branch point. Now the phase of $\sqrt{z-ic}$  changes by $\pi$, when $z$ encircles the point $c$. Thus the values of $\sqrt{z-ic}$  for $z = i\xi + \epsilon$ and $z = i\xi - \epsilon$ are negatives of each other.

Comment: Thank you again. I see my error now:

I set up the contour with branch cuts from $z=i[c,\infty)$ and $z=i(-\infty,-c]$ due to the $(z-ic)^{1/2}$ and $(z+ic)^{1/2}$ factors, respectively; however, I _incorrectly_ applied the branch cut at $z=i[c,\infty)$ to the $(z+ic)^{1/2}$ factor [which gave an additional $e^{i\pi}$, cancelling out the $e^{i\pi}$ factor from the $(z-ic)^{1/2}$ factor, resulting in my error].

Kudos to you for your insight!